# How to include subscript and superscript in TEXT function output in Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've searched, but not found a solution to the following.

I have a formula which converts a value from `decimal inches` in cell `A1` to a `vulgar fraction` in cell `B1`, so:

> 13.4 converts to 1′-1 3/8″

The formula in cell B1 is:

```
=INT(MROUND(A1,1/8)/12)&"′-"&TEXT(MOD(MROUND(A1,1/8),12),"0 #/###""″""")
```

Now, I’d like to see the output formatted thus:

> 1′-1 ⅜″

In other words, I want to format the first # as superscript and the ### following the solidus to subscript.

I can achieve this manually if typing the value in the cell, by selecting the character 3 and then choosing `Format|Format Cells|Superscript` and so on, but I'd like to know if there is a way to adapt the formula to include this dynamically as output. I prefer not to have to resort to a macro.

Comment: Hi Richard.........possible with a macro, but still difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting task! How about using Unicode vulgar fraction symbols?

```
=INT(A1/12)&"′ "&INT(MOD(A1,12))&INDEX({"","⅛","¼","⅜","½","⅝","¾","⅞"},FLOOR(MOD(A1,1),1/8)*8+1)&"″"
```